# Copying graphs as pictures to a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I can simply take data from my "Main" workbook, and copy it to my "wbnew" workbook as values only(V). This makes it so that formulas in rows are not a factor. I noticed there is also a picture paste option for graphs(U). Below I have displayed how I could easily do it woth values only. How could I go about doing it pictures only for my graphs sheet?

```
    Main.Worksheets("Histogram data").Copy Before:=wbnew.Sheets(1)
With wbnew.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    .Value = .Value 'converts formulas to values
End With
```

.

```
    Main.Worksheets("Histogram graphs").Copy Before:=wbnew.Sheets(1)
With wbnew.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    .Pictures = .Pictures 'converts graphs to pictures
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN you can use the [following method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/chart-copypicture-method-excel) to copies the selected object to the clipboard as a picture.

The following code should work in your case:

```
Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture
Sheet2.Paste
```

Regards,
Teasel

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chartname").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

Range("A1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Paste.Select
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.